Cannot fix INP issues
I'm trying to improve my INP to match google search console requirements. It seems i'm sitting just after 200ms since a long time.
I analyzed my website with debugbear tool, which seems to indicate that everything is ok.
I set up a loading gif, and indicate a "loading" when an user clicks the main form buttons.
It's been a few weeks but still no changes in search console.
I can't seem to understand what part of my pages are responsible for this high INP.
Would you have any recommendation ?
Here's my website btw.
Thank you for your enlightments.

INP is a hard one to debug, as it requires user interactions. Something testing tools like Page Speed Insights do not do.
You can gather your detailed user metrics for your own website. Here's an article on it:
https://web.dev/articles/vitals-field-measurement-best-practices
As these are real user metrics, it does pick up INP, what element is involved, and which pages it is happening on. A lot more info to help you work out where the problem is.
You can also manually test interactions in the Chrome Lighthouse recording a timespan, and in the performance report doing a recording.

Thank you for your answer. I will check that out, I actually never tried the timespan option in lighthouse.

Have you checked your website with Page Speed Insights?
Just ran it and got a detailed answer where what is wrong).
Here are the results of tests of your site, by the way on the desktop everything is very good.

Thank you for your answer. I use a lot pagespeed, even though I tend to prefer other tools such as debugbear or gtmetrix. I realized that my optimization for recaptcha, which was to load the script at the first user click, may affect my inp as I didn't attach it specifically to the form, which may cause a delay when the user clicks on the menu for instance. I modified that. I cannot seem to see exactly from which part of the page the high INP comes though, pagespeed doesn't provide insights on INP. It's a shame mobile is the default for performance as it represents only 5% of my traffic.
